# Error System.Windows.Media.Color.A.get

Tags: c#

I have a project that is an image editor and I erroneous reference markets 'System.Windows.Media.Color.A.get' and not because I make that mistake this is the brand I Error code in Visual Studio 2012 is for windows phone 8

Would greatly appreciate your help

```
        public WriteableBitmap Process(WriteableBitmap input)
    {
        var result = new WriteableBitmap(input.PixelWidth, input.PixelHeight);
        var resultPixels = result.Pixels;
        var inputPixels = input.Pixels;
        var ta = Color.A;
        var tr = Color.R;
        var tg = Color.G;
        var tb = Color.B;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputPixels.Length; i++)
        {
            var c = inputPixels[i];
            var a = (byte)(c >> 24);
            var r = (byte)(c >> 16);
            var g = (byte)(c >> 8);
            var b = (byte)(c);

            int gray = (r * 6966 + g * 23436 + b * 2366) >> 15;

            a = (byte)((a    * ta) >> 8);
            r = (byte)((gray * ta) >> 8);
            g = (byte)((gray * ta) >> 8);
            b = (byte)((gray * ta) >> 8);

            resultPixels[i] = (a << 24) |
                (r << 16) |
                (g << 8) |
                b;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Wait, what's the problem? Does Visual Studio give you a line number where the error is?

Comment: Could you add periods/full stops to your question?

Answer (score 1):

what you expected to do from below lines?

```
var ta = Color.A;
var tr = Color.R;
var tg = Color.G;
var tb = Color.B;
```

According to Error you are using `System.Windows.Media.Color` class and the properties called 'A,R,G,B' All those are public properties but you call those as static properties. if you need to access non static property you need to create object of it.